# Any workaround to avoid changing IE security settings while using Selenium 2.28?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar to automate a web application behavior. I am using Internet Explorer 9 to test the application.

Previously I was using selenium-server-standalone-2.17.0.jar version for the same set of test cases without having any trouble. But when I updated the jar version to 2.28, the application could not run the test cases in Internet Explorer. I found out that for this Selenium version, I need to have IEDriverServer_Win32_2.28.0 and need to set webdriver.ie.driver system property with the IEDriverServer path.

Furthermore, I need to set Protected Mode settings for all zones in Internet Explorer, which leads the antivirus in my system blocking the IEDriverServer.exe from running. I need to bypass the antivirus to test my application.

The problem is in any enterprise system, developers are not allowed to change any IE security related settings. Even if they can do so, allowing an application bypassing antivirus is almost next to impossible. My question here is is whether there is any workaround to achieve this?

Thanks,
Rana Banerjee

Answer (score 0):

You have some options available to you. There is a capability you can set on the IE driver that will bypass the Protected Mode check. However, before you resort to this approach, I implore you to read (and have your "enterprise IT security" team read) [this blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) for a thorough explanation of why this is a bad idea.

Additionally, it might be worth clarifying what you mean by your antivirus software "blocking the IEDriverSErver.exe from running." Does it not launch at all? Does it run, but your WebDriver code throw an exception? Or do you mean something else?

If the antivirus software is actually preventing IEDriverServer.exe from executing, it likely isn't having an issue with IEDriverServer.exe because of Protected Mode settings. It's far more likely that it has an issue with the executable extracting a randomly-named .dll to the temp directory and loading it. There's a command-line switch on IEDriverServer.exe to control which directory is used for the extraction; you'll need to consult your language bindings to figure out how to pass it to the executable.

Comment: The IEDriverServer is actually starting from my code, listening to some random port. After that, the antivirus software is denying the IE from launching.

Comment: Two follow-up questions: First, how do you **know** it's the antivirus software preventing IE from launching? Second, if you change the logging level for IEDriverServer.exe to a more verbose level (you'll need to consult the documentation for your language binding for instructions on how to do this), what does the log point to as being wrong?